# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() throws WebException

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using the latest version of Monodroid, 4.04, and am trying to connect to a device using HttpWebRequest. The problem I am running into is the GetResponse is throwing a webexception (see below). 
In the debugger, when I set a breakpoint, I can see that webRequest.HaveResponse == true, but the response is null in the exception.

Why can't I get to the response when it reports that has a response?

The code I am using:

```
string responseFromServer;
        ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new TestCertificatePolicy();

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.1.1/login.cgi");
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStreamIn = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

        dataStreamIn.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStreamIn.Close();

        try
        {
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse(); <-- throws webexception
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(we);
            throw;
        }
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:    at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone(IAsyncResult result)
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x0003a] in /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:399 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:828 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /home/jon/Development/xamarin/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:836 
  at MonoDroidTest.Activity1.GetStreamPage (System.String url) [0x000c2] in C:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MonoDroidTest\MonoDroidTest\Activity1.cs:277
```

Comment: Is there a nested exception at all?

Comment: Are you able to hit that URL using the Browser app?

Comment: Yes, everything works great in the browser. I am away from work now, but I think it could be caused by the server sending non-standard headers. Here is the article I found in which the poster had a similar issue, thoughts?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812047/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-for-net-compact-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to say that I ended up solving this problem by using a socket. This is probably a better way anyway due to the nature of the data.