# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Please, someone help me.  I've been researching this for hours, have tried lots of different suggested fixes, and I'm at a total loss as to why I am still getting this error.

I have an *ASP.NET 4.0* web page with the following code in it:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetHref);
// request.KeepAlive = false;
// request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
// request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I've tried every combination I can imagine of un-commenting the above 3 commented lines.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<system.net>
   <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing ="true"/>
   </settings>
</system.net>
```

When I am running *Fiddler* on my dev machine, the page runs without exception and fiddler shows this message at the top of the return:

> HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers

Without Fiddler running, I get the error every time on the `request.GetResponse()` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I tried every suggestion I could find here on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the web, but never got an implementation of HttpWebRequest to work for me, so I tried using TcpClient instead after reading this:
[How To Set useUnsafeHeaderParsing For .NET Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812047/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-for-net-compact-framework)

To get it to work for me, I had to modify this line:

```
 sw.WriteLine(string.Format("GET /{0} HTTP/1.1", pathAndQueryString));
```

to:

```
 sw.WriteLine(string.Format("GET /{0} {1}", pathAndQueryString, Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine));
```

And that worked.

Comment: Who-hoo! You saved me a lot of work with Environment.NewLine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net with C# this issue is associated with port only.

Many programs use 80 port thats why you get this error, so get rid of this issue no configuration is required just close your

Skype, VPN softwares etc.. and it will resolve your issue.

In my case actually it was not Skype but hotspot shield (a free VPN) software was running in background quitting that software resolved my issue.